# MFC: Getting edit control text and splitting it to 2 dimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, mfc

I have edit control and masked edit control on a form. Upon wrinting and losing focus in masked control a number (up to 99), edit box fills up with adjacency matrix. Later on I want to use it to represent edges and finding cycles in graph. I am pulling up text from edit box like this:

```
CString x;
GetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT, x);
```

My data in edit box upon losing focus look like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

But is it possible to split all numbers (delimeter here is " ") into 2 dimensional array, like C++ vector?

Comment: An edit control contains just a string. You see several lines because inside that string there are *new line* separators (i.e. '\n' or CR&LF chars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `stl` (a combination of `istringstream` and `getline`) or chose a more `MFC` approach:

```
CString s;
// ...
int lpos = 0;
for (CString line = s.Tokenize(_T("\n"), lpos); lpos > 0; line = s.Tokenize(_T("\n"), lpos))
{
  int cpos = 0;
  for (CString cell = line.Tokenize(_T(" "), cpos); cpos > 0; cell = line.Tokenize(_T(" "), cpos))
  {
    // your cell processing 
  }
}
```